# if the device is ios 5

Tags: ios5

How can I determine if the device that is running my app is ios 5?

I'm trying to use the UIAppearance class but it will give an error if it's running on ios versions other than 5. so I want to have if statement that only runs this line of code if the device is ios5.

Thanks,

EDIT:
SO here is the solution,

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

if (version >= 5.0){

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}
```

Comment: I generally use `respondsToSelector:` if the reason for the test is to avoid calling an iOS 5 selector on iOS 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the OS version using

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

But a better way would be to check for specific features, Something along the lines of

```
if(NSProtocolFromString(@"UIAppearance")) {
    // Do something
}
```

To see if that class is available, then perform you operations.
Failing that it is also possible to make sure you only build for iOS 5, and it will only install on iOS 5 devices.

Comment: the check returns nil when I run it on ios 4 which is correct, but it also returns nil on ios 5! so instead of NSClassFromString(@"UIAppearance"), I used [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]. Thank you so much :)

Comment: NSClassFromString(@"UIAppearance") is not correct - you should use NSProtocolFromString(@"UIAppearance") instead.